# Numbers/Excel Hour Counter within Specified Date Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, iwork-numbers, worksheet-function

[image: Spreadsheet Example]

The data shown in the image is just sample information but...
I would like to use the "Period Beginning" and "Period End" to create a range to determine the total number of hours and earnings. I have tried many different functions in different many different ways and keep getting either "0" or syntax error. Any ideas?

Hour count=G2-B2-(D2-C2)-(F2-E2)

Comment: Hello benjamin, what Excel version do you use? English or non-english Excel version? Are the values in column A and B stored as date and formatted as "weekday, month day, year"? Thats the usual scenario

Comment: It is 2011 English. They are in date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the upper screenshot data is in Sheet2, with the column headers in row 1, which will put the "Hour Count" column in column H,

further assuming that the values in column H are real time values, not text values concatenated to look fancy,

further assuming that the lower screenshot is in Sheet1,

this formula in Sheet1, starting in cell C2 and copied down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100>=Sheet1!A2),--(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100<=Sheet1!B2),Sheet2!$H$2:$H$100)
```

Looking at the warning triangles in the upper screenshot, it looks as if the "Hour Count" may be something other than a real number, so, it would help if you could post the formula that lives in column H, and whatever else you did to that column to make it look like it does.

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely forgot about this.